# html <base> affecting Iframe "src" tag with external link

Tags: html, iframe, base-url

I have a base url `<base href="https://www.example.com/" target="_self">` for my page's relative links.
The problem is, it's affecting the **src=""** of an external iframe am trying to embed.

```
​<iframe width="600" height="300" frameborder="0" src="​https://external-example.to/something/widget?width=600&height=300&note=​"></iframe>
```

Other iframes loading content from the my domain `https://www.example.com/` are working just fine.

Forexample `<iframe width="600" height="300" frameborder="0" src="​https://www.example.com/something/some-thing"></iframe>` is not affected.

The **base url** if forcing it's value on the **src** value of the external iframe like this

```
​<iframe width="600" height="300" frameborder="0" src="​https://www.example.com/​https://external-example.to/something/widget?width=600&height=300&note=​"></iframe>
```

How can I avoid this **`https://www.example.com/​https://external-example.to/something/widget?width=600&height=300&note=`​** from happening?

Thanks.